# Why -use-network=false

Tags: apache-flex

Dose anyone knows why I have to use -use-network=false in my Flex Builder?!?!?!

This is set inside the Project Properties and is Additional compiler argument.

This is only when I want to read in a external file like XML.

Others in my team doesn't have to have -use-network=false ????

Comment: We sometimes create Flex applications which will be launched from a USB-stick (by creating a Projector from within Flash Player) which loads an XML file in the same directory as the application. That would be local access, which raises a sandbox security error. To let your application access local files and test it's behaviour, -use-network=false comes in very handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If other members of your team don't have to use -use-network=false then they probably have global trust permisions set up. You can't access local files with a Flash file ordinarily, for good security reasons. When you're developing though you need to be able to access files locally. To do that, you have two options:

1. -use-network=false inverts the trust, but on deploying you have to revert it back;
2. set global permissions so that within your dev folder, these rules don't apply: [see this post for details](http://blog.vizio360.co.uk/2009/08/flash-player-trust-file-mac-windows-and-linux/)

Answer (score 2):

Network access and local file access are mutually exclusive in Flash/Flex. The [documentation](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_14.html) for the use-network compiler option explains it best:

> When the `use-network` property is set to `false`, the application can access the local filesystem (for example, use the XML.load() method with file: URLs) but not network services. In most circumstances, the value of this property should be true.
>
> For more information about the use-network property, see [Applying Flex Security](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/html/security2_01.html#137544).

Comment: I see. But will my application work once I deploy it on a remote server then?

Comment: Once it's on the remote system, having `use-network` set to true will mean that it can access the user's machine, but not any files on the server on which it's hosted.