# Flash Builder Output is Blank

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, flash-builder

I am a Flash Builder 4 noobie here, and I began working on a simple application, to try out FB 4. However, I am having a problem.

When a compile and run the application, the output is entirely blank. The HTML wrapper page *does* contain the flash application, but the content is blank, even though I have a simple label component on the stage.

Also I noticed that when I right-click on the flash object, the default context menu appears, displaying the "Zoom In", "Zoom Out", "Show All", etc... options which are removed from the application by default.

If you are interested, here is my code, as easy as it gets. :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

  <fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
  </fx:Declarations>

  <s:Label x="100" y="100" text="Hello World" fontWeight="bold" fontSize="18"/>
</s:Application>
```

I am running Flash Player 10.2. Can anyone help work out this issue?

Thank you for your time,
spryno724

Comment: erm, some code would be nice? are you sure it's building properly?  Do you have your 'build automatically' flag on?

Comment: No, I choose "Run" -> "Run _<application name>_" option each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it would be difficult to be exact, I think I understand the issue.

I assume you are loading your swf file from local machine.(File: protocol). By default this behavior is considered a security violation and hence for development you need to use -use-network=false compiler setting. This will allow you to load your swf file from file system. You might want to remove this. once you are porting it to production.

Comment: more details on this stackoverflow thread,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198857/why-use-network-false

Comment: In anticipation of future data-centric applications I will build, I placed this experimental folder under the "htdocs" folder of my PHP server. Once I accessed via the server, it fired right up! Thanks for your time, doc_180!

Comment: btw, thanks for the follow-up link I could use read-up on this.