# AS3 URLRequest works locally, not on server

Tags: php, json, actionscript-3, cross-domain, flashdevelop

so I have a URL Request I'm making to a site.. and everything works fine locally but on the server it doesn't.

I have tried with a crossdomain file but am not sure if I am doing it properly or not.. Here is my request (URLs changed for security purposes).

```
var ureq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://this.that.site.com/Live/V6/this.svc/GetUserProfile");
ureq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
ureq.data = JSON.encode(uvars);

ureq.contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

var uload:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
uload.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, responseJSONCaches);
uload.load(ureq);
```

Response is just a simple trace to firebug.

My crossdomain.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

which is currently just for testing purposes until I figure out the issue I will limit other domains.

Can someone give me some insight to this. I rarely visit these issues so I'm a little in the dark.

Comment: What's your IDE?   FlashPro? FlashDevelop? FlashBuilder?

Comment: If FlashPro, you have to make sure you export with the appropriate "Local playback security" in the publish settings

Comment: In FlashDevelop, there is an option in your project property compiler options called "Use Network Services", you could try flipping it's value, though it should default to what you want so it probably isn't the issue

Comment: Some more information.. after digging a bit and adding a bunch of event listeners to the URLRequest, I've determined it's a crossdomain.xml issue.. Here is the Error I'm getting:

`code
[SecurityErrorEvent type="securityError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2048"]
`

Comment: try using this:  http://www.securitybughunter.com/tools/crossdomainxml/

Comment: Make sure that your firewall is not blocked, place crossdomain.xml in root of server and set compiler argument use-network=true

Comment: Please follow stackoverflow link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198857/why-use-network-false

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Wasn't an issue on my end. The client never had their crossdomain.xml setup properly -_-